# Mirror-API: Can html cards be shared to Google+ contacts?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am trying to share timeline cards with Google+ contacts. All the testing I've done is with one-to-one (private) shares.

If I set only the 'html' property, the share will be blank (other than the #throughglass tag).

If I set only the 'text' property, the share will include the string value that 'text' is set to (and the hash tag).

If I set both the 'html' and 'text' properties, the share will include the string value that 'text' is set to (and the hash tag).

Is this the expected behavior, or is there a way to share html content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

If you want to share HTML content, you can add a custom menu option, which will send the timeline item and all its parameters to your server. You can then parse the timeline item's HTML parameter and [send it to Google+ with the Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert).